# How to display labels in pie transition chart using d3.js?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, charts, pie-chart

I am using pie transition chart of d3.js to visualize the potential customers.
The graph is drawn, but the labels are not displayed on the graph.

Here is the code:

```
var w = 400,
h = 400,
r = Math.min(w, h) / 2,
data = [25,45],            // Data values
color = d3.scale.category20(),
arc = d3.svg.arc().outerRadius(r),
donut = d3.layout.pie();

var vis = d3.select("#pie-chart-div").append("svg")  // Place the chart in 'pie-chart-div'
    .data([data])
    .attr("width", w)
    .attr("height", h);

var arcs = vis.selectAll("g.arc")
    .data(donut)
  .enter().append("g")
    .attr("class", "arc")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + r + "," + r + ")");

var paths = arcs.append("path")
    .attr("fill", function(d, i) { return color(i); });

paths.transition()
    .ease("bounce")
    .duration(2000)
    .attrTween("d", tweenPie);

paths.transition()
    .ease("elastic")
    .delay(function(d, i) { return 2000 + i * 50; })
    .duration(750)
    .attrTween("d", tweenDonut);

function tweenPie(b) {
  b.innerRadius = 0;
  var i = d3.interpolate({startAngle: 0, endAngle: 0}, b);
  return function(t) {
    return arc(i(t));
  };
}

function tweenDonut(b) {
  b.innerRadius = r * .6;
  var i = d3.interpolate({innerRadius: 0}, b);
  return function(t) {
    return arc(i(t));
  };
}
```

**How to display labels in the pie transition chart ?**

Comment: "The graph is drawn, but the labels are not displayed on the graph"... the reason is simple: you're not appending any text element to the groups. So, the labels won't show up automagically.

Comment: Tried this code. But it doesn't display in the exact location, on the sectors.
    arcs.append("text")
     .text(function(d, i) { return d.value.toFixed(2); });

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To display the text in the "exact location" (which I supposed is in the middle of the arc), you can use the `centroid()` function:

```
var labels = arcs.append("text")
    .attr("transform", function(d) { 
        d.innerRadius = 120;
        return "translate(" + arc.centroid(d) + ")"; 
    })
    .attr("dy", ".35em")
    .text(function(d) { return d.value; });
```

Check this demo:

```js
var w = 400,
h = 400,
r = Math.min(w, h) / 2,
data = [25,45],            // Data values
color = d3.scale.category20(),
arc = d3.svg.arc().outerRadius(r),
donut = d3.layout.pie();

var vis = d3.select("body").append("svg")  // Place the chart in 'pie-chart-div'
    .data([data])
    .attr("width", w)
    .attr("height", h);

var arcs = vis.selectAll("g.arc")
    .data(donut)
  .enter().append("g")
    .attr("class", "arc")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + r + "," + r + ")");

var paths = arcs.append("path")
    .attr("fill", function(d, i) { return color(i); });
  
var labels = arcs.append("text")
      .attr("transform", function(d) { d.innerRadius = 120; return "translate(" + arc.centroid(d) + ")"; })
      .attr("dy", ".35em")
      .text(function(d) { return d.value; });

paths.transition()
    .ease("bounce")
    .duration(2000)
    .attrTween("d", tweenPie);

paths.transition()
    .ease("elastic")
    .delay(function(d, i) { return 2000 + i * 50; })
    .duration(750)
    .attrTween("d", tweenDonut);

function tweenPie(b) {
  b.innerRadius = 0;
  var i = d3.interpolate({startAngle: 0, endAngle: 0}, b);
  return function(t) {
    return arc(i(t));
  };
}

function tweenDonut(b) {
  b.innerRadius = r * .6;
  var i = d3.interpolate({innerRadius: 0}, b);
  return function(t) {
    return arc(i(t));
  };
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Yes, now it is fine.
When labels are added to data:


data = [{"label":"sector1", "value":25}, 
            {"label":"sector2", "value":45}]
"NaN" is displayed instead of the chart.

Comment: As this is another problem, please post it as a new question, and I'll have a look at it.

Comment: I've posted a new question. Please have a look into it:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40522720/label-names-are-not-displayed-from-input-data-in-pie-transition-chart-of-d3-js